# Is this a SQL Non-Alpha Numeric value?

Tags: sql

I ran the query below to find non-alphanumeric values in my table and go the following results.

```
  where  NOT LIKE  '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

However, it was returning Non-alphanumeric values.

> Results: 00003000000DDE11003

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, the problem is probably due to a character that you cannot see.

Comment: `0` is *not* `LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'` (because of the `^`) your `NOT` then inverts this to give you the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @AlexK. . . . I think the OP is looking for non-alphanumeric characters, as suggested in the title.

Comment: in (standard) SQL, the `LIKE` operator does **NOT** use regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. You are asking for a double negative by using both `NOT` and `^`.

Currently you are asking for records where a column is not-not alphanumeric.

So this should work the way you expect: `WHERE column NOT LIKE '%[0-9A-Za-z]%'`

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. For example I have data the has "*" in the value and it is not returned by the where  NOT LIKE  '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'

Comment: I've edited the answer to one that works, although there is a way to use the NOT LIKE syntax to get this, and if someone shares it I recommend it over what I've done. I just tested this in a sqlfiddle and it seems to do what you want.

Comment: It doesn't work. It needs to be Not lIke because * is not alphanumeric

Comment: If I run like, then Will get all the valid data in the output

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you want -- I've validated that this answer returns a record that has a column with the value of "*".

Comment: Correct, it does. But also returns all other records that are Alpha numeric.

Comment: My mistake, I updated it the wrong way, try now. Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/098da5/11